# How to scroll input type="range" by values from datalist

Tags: html, input

I read that `input type="range"` [supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#try_it) the attribute `list`. So I have the following example:

```
<input type="range" list="values">
<datalist id="values">
    <option value="0">
    <option value="30">
    <option value="40">
    <option value="60">
    <option value="100">
</datalist>
```

I need to scroll only by the specified values the same as I specified a step. That is after `0` I need to jump to `30` when scrolling, then to `40` and so on. But I still can scroll by all possible values which are available by default i.e. `0, 1, 2, 3` etc (and I just feel snapping on the positions of the specified values).

In other words, I need `input type="range"` with "float" or "dynamic" step depending on the values from the list (30-0=30, 40-30=10, 60-40=20 etc.).

Is that possible with this type of input?

Comment: From the same page you linked: "The values provided are suggestions, not requirements: users can select from this predefined list or provide a different value." The behavior is intended. If you want custom behavior, you're going to need to write some Javascript. Though, to be honest, "range with a custom list of non-uniform values" sounds to be more like a [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). If I had a range that scrolled the way you describe, I'd be very frustrated as a user.

Answer (score 2):

Natively in HTML you will not be able to force a `range` input to *irregular, predefined steps*. There is a `step` attribute for this type of input, however this allows for setting *evenly spaced, predefined steps*.

JavaScript can add this type of functionality, and how specific you get with your irregular spacing can vary pretty widely.

For this example, I kept it simple. The script gets a list from your **values** `datalist` and then whenever the input is changed, it finds the closest value and ***snaps*** to that instead.

```js
let steps = [];
document.querySelectorAll("#values option").forEach(o => {
  steps.push(o.value);
});

document.querySelector("#slider").addEventListener("change", e => {
  steps.forEach((v, i) => {
    if(e.target.value <= parseFloat(v) && !steps.includes(e.target.value)) {
      e.target.value = (i > 0) ? ((parseFloat(v)-e.target.value) < (parseFloat(v)-parseFloat(steps[i-1]))/2) ? v : steps[i-1] : v;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" list="values" value="40" style="width: 400px;">
<datalist id="values">
    <option value="0">
    <option value="30">
    <option value="40">
    <option value="60">
    <option value="100">
</datalist>
```